# Linux device driver char device synchronization between unregister and release

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have a device driver with `misc_register()` API being called to create a serial device. Now, I want to call `misc_deregister()` because the device does not function any more due to hardware change (for example removal of cable of the serial port). Now the application has opened this device and performing operations on it, so there is an open file descriptor for this device.

I want to know if the driver wait for the application to call `release` (or `close()` API) on the device before calling `misc_deregister()`? Or can the driver call `misc_deregister()` and then it can still receive a (last) `release` callback?

Comment: Do you mean you try to remove the `/dev` node for this serial device when you fail to read form it? I'm asking because, according to [misc_deregister](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/drivers/char/misc.c#L251) code, device_destroy will remove the `/dev` node. I think you should just close the device. You don't have to call `misc_deregister`.

Comment: closing the device can be done from the application. is it okay to close the device from the kernel, before application does it?

Comment: If `read`, `write` or other calls fail, let the application handle it.